# Posting data from multiple servers routing through one server to client server

Tags: networking

I have 5 webservers behind Load balancer and we have a client server at other end. Client has white listed my 5 webserver public ip so that my webservers will post a file to the client server. Here the problem is my webservers is going to increase and i cannot always ask client to make my new webserver ip's white list. So i would like to make my infra this way, my webservers will post data to the client server routing from a single server. Like assume that web-1 is main server and the remaining 4 web servers will post data to client server routing through main web-1.

I was told that this can be achieved by doing IP Tunneling. But i have no idea how to do that. Would be great for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a load-balancer. Load-balancers are the solution to the many-to-one problem of networks, and you're already using it to do that for your own infrastructure.

You now have a many-to-one problem going the other way. The quick solution to this is to turn it around; put the client's IP as a backend resource on it and have your webservers POST to the IP address on the load-balancer.